# Deriving expression for Variance in Time Series (example)

Tags: time-series, variance, arima, mean, autoregressive

Given an $ARIMA(1, 2, 0)$ process $X_t$, let $\nabla^2X_t = Y_t$, then $Y_t = \alpha Y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$ is a stationary $AR(1)$ process.

(Here $\nabla$ is the difference operator such that $\nabla X_t = X_t - X_{t-1}$)

$\epsilon_t$ here is white noise, normally distributed as such $\epsilon_t \sim N(0, \sigma^2_{\epsilon})$

I want to be able to derive $var(\overline{Y} )$ where $\overline{Y}$ is the sample mean of $Y_1, Y_2, \dots, Y_n$. How would this be achieved?